# How do I establish a comparator for a set c++

Tags: c++, set, comparator

I have a set, and for this set, I need two different comparators. For example, for a set `frontier` I need to sort by cost, but I have another set `board` which needs to be sorted by coordinates. I know you *can* define a comparator for each set using the comparator as the second argument, but I have tried this and it gave me an error.

The code I tried to use:

```
struct tile {
int id;
int xCord;
int yCord;
int cost;

...

bool operator<(const tile& Rhs) const {

    if (cost < Rhs.cost) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (cost < Rhs.cost) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (id < Rhs.id) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }


}

...


};
```

The other struct that I'm using for the comparator (I know this is most likely incorrect, which is why I'm asking for help.):

```
struct costComp {
int id;
int xCord;
int yCord;
int cost;

costComp() {}

costComp(int a, int b, int c, int d = 0) :
    id(a),
    xCord(b),
    yCord(c),
    cost(d) {}


bool operator<( const tile& Rhs) const {
    if (xCord < Rhs.xCord)
        return true;
    else if (xCord < Rhs.xCord)
        return false;
    else {
        if (yCord < Rhs.yCord)
            return true;
        else if (yCord < Rhs.yCord)
            return false;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
};
```

Then, I define the set as:

```
set<tile,costComp> startBoard;
```

The error I got:

```
c2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A comparator for a set compares ***two values in the set***, and not one value in the set against something. Your `operator<` overload must take two tile values, and specify whether they're strict weak-ordered.

Comment: You may want to use [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to simplify all of that error-prone logic.  The example on that page shows exactly how to remove all that logic into a simple comparison.

Comment: Defining `operator<(const tile&) const` inside of the `costComp` means the operator gets used as `someCostComp < someTile`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So are you saying I should have a lhs *and* a rhs in my comparison?

Comment: Yes, after all, that's what the `<` operator does. It compares its left value to its right value. Your `tile`'s class `<` operator compares something to itself, essentially `*this` being its left-hand side. A set's comparator has two values to work with, and its job is to compare them. ... Actually I stand corrected. The comparator must implement the () operator.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I thought the same thing when I implemented that originally. However, it gives me a syntax error saying "too many parameters for this operator function" if I implement a lhs as well.

Comment: I stand corrected. The comparator needs to implement the `()` operator, not the `<` operator.

Comment: Thank you! Will I use the comparator the same way that I use the < operator? Sorry, this overloaded operator is the one I understand the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `Compare` parameter in `std::set` is intended to be some callable type that can be invoked with `(const tile&, const tile&)`. This means you can use a functor that overloads `operator()`, for example, like this:

```
struct Comp {
    bool operator()(const tile& lhs, const tile& rhs) const {
        if (lhs.id < rhs.id) return true;
        if (lhs.id > rhs.id) return false;
        if (lhs.xCord < rhs.xCord) return true;
        if (lhs.xCord > rhs.xCord) return false;
        if (lhs.yCord < rhs.yCord) return true;
        if (lhs.yCord > rhs.yCord) return false;
        return lhs.cost < rhs.cost;
    }
    // or maybe, if this logic already exists:
    bool operator()(const tile& lhs, const tile& rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs; // invoke tile::operator<(const tile&)
    }
};

...

std::set<tile, Comp> myset;
```

This way, the comparator struct doesn't need to keep track of the details of any one `tile` object, and the redundant members of `costComp` can be removed.

---

If you want the comparator to be configurable, you can add members to the `Comp` struct definition and initialize them in a constructor call when you instantiate the set:

```
struct Comp {
    Comp(bool use_cost = false /* default behavior */) : m_use_cost(use_cost) {}

    bool operator()(const tile& lhs, const tile& rhs) const {
        if (m_use_cost){
            return lhs.cost < rhs.cost;
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
private:
    const bool m_use_cost;
};

...
// default comparison, won't use cost
std::set<tile, Comp> setA;
// specify custom behaviour
std::set<tile, Comp> setB {Comp{true /* right here */}};
```

Obviously, the configurability is not limited to one or more `bools`. It might make sense to have some `enum` with values like `SortByCost`, `SortByXcoord`. Alternatively, you could have a separate functor struct that does each, but this means that sets with different comparators will have different types and will not be inter-copyable or moveable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to compare using the coordinates if I don't add the custom comparator as the second argument in the set. But if I do add in the second argument, I want to be able to compare using the cost. If I just use the coordinates in the overloaded () operator, will it achieve my goal?

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this will get me to my goal behavior!

Comment: Hi, I've implemented your code, but I'm getting an error saying "invalid comparator"

Comment: @MatthewVanlandingham that's a very vague description. If it helps, [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3f86652f2bf1543) is an example I wrote while testing my answer. You may try to follow it and start small and simple and add features until something refuses to compile.

Comment: I apologize. I made a simple error with my comparisons. All good now!

Comment: @alterigel `bool operator() (const tile& lhs, const tile& rhs) const {return std::tie(lhs.id, lhs.xCord, lhs.yCord, lhs.cost) < std::tie(rhs.id, rhs.xCord, rhs.yCord, rhs.cost);}` -- This is what I stated in my comment.  All of that logic is condensed into that one line using `std::tie`.